# Работа исключения InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, исключения, конструктор

Экспериментируя с рефлексией, я наткнулся на один интересный момент в исключениях, который никак не могу понять.

Есть возможность объединять исключения в так называемые цепочки, при помощи метода `initCause()` или конструкторов, принимающих `Throwable` или `String` и `Throwable`.

Про метод `initCause()` в документации написано следующее:

> This method can be called at most once. It is generally called from within the constructor, or immediately after creating the throwable. If this throwable was created with Throwable(Throwable) or Throwable(String, Throwable), this method cannot be called even once.

То есть, мы создаём цепочку исключений либо вызывая метод `initCause()` (максимум один раз), либо при помощи конструкторов родительского для всех исключений класса `Throwable`. Во втором случае мы, вызвав один из обозначенных конструкторов, больше не сможем вызвать метод `initCause()`.

Теперь же приведу конструкторы исключения `InvocationTargetException`, которые меня и заинтересовали.

```
protected InvocationTargetException() {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
}

public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
    this.target = target;
}

public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target, String s) {
    super(s, null);  // Disallow initCause
    this.target = target;
}
```

Логику первого конструктора, хотя он `protected`, я понять ещё могу. Мы не передаём причину сразу же при вызове конструктора, значит, запретим указывать её и потом. Наверно, какой-то смысл в этом есть.

Но вот два других конструктора я не понимаю. Благодаря первой строчке в обоих конструкторах мы запрещаем дальнейший вызов `initCause()`, а затем своему собственному полю `target` типа `Throwable` присваиваем причину, плюс к этому метод `getCause()` от класса `Throwable` переопределяется, так, чтобы он возвращал это самое наше поле.

**Вопрос**: зачем? Ведь оба конструктора мы могли написать так:

```
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super(target);
}

public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target, String s) {
    super(s, target);
}
```

В таком случае мы вполне корректно создали бы цепочку исключений, точно так же сразу же запретив дальнейший вызов `initCause()`, и при таком подходе у нас нет нужды хранить своё поле, переопределять метод `getCause()`, и в целом запись конструкторов становится более короткой и понятной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Throwable.getCause()` появился позже чем `InvocationTargetException`, так что убрать метод `getTargetException()` было уже нельзя. Но почему не убрали поле `target` -- я не знаю. Может, просто поленились -- что толку оптимизировать исключения

Comment: Про время появления класса `InvocationTargetException` вы хорошо заметили, я об этом как-то не подумал. Действительно, он старше, чем методы `initCause()` и `getCause()` и конструкторы класса `Throwable`, принимающие `Throwable`. Так что, видимо, такой вид этого класса обусловлен тем, что сначала, до появления инструментов для создания цепочки исключений, цепочка создавалась самостоятельно, при помощи своего поля `target`, а потом с появлением обновлений в класс просто вносили определённые изменения. Спасибо за ответ.